# Trying to understand JSONP on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

Well i would like to know something about JSONP,

like when someone enter in my website and i do a ajax request with dataType JSONP,

this request will be done like when this same person enter direct in this page? i.e: this page that ajax will request with JSONP get the IP of the user,

it will get the real ip of this user? similar to a iframe i mean.

thanks.

Comment: You question might be unclear. But the IP visible by the server is the same whatever the type of request.

Comment: JSONP is actually no Ajax call. It's including a `script` element referring to an external script (does not have to be external though), just like you include jQuery from a CDN.

Comment: Well if i do a ajax request JSONP in some url that counts downloads for IP it will be counted isn't? cuz it will use the user ip, isn't?

Comment: Since all of the Internet communication is based on the IP protocol (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol), yes, any connection will involve IP addresses. JSONP and Ajax are protocols/techniques at a much higher level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every request to a server contains the client's `IP` address. This also applies to `JSONP`, which is implemented using an HTTP `GET` request.

Comment: +1 correct. I fixed your formatting. If I recall correctly this is in fact because of the underlying TCP protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the call is made by the browser, so it will use the IP address and settings of the user.

A JSONP call is actually a script tag that makes the request, so it will look to the server just as any other script tag loading script from the server.